# How can I remove/delete an answer on the mobile App?

Tags: support, bug, android-app, vote-to-delete

I'm using the Android App of Stack Exchange.
Today I wanted to comment on a question (on Ask Ubuntu), but instead I accidentally hit the Answer button.

When I realized I wanted to delete my Answer, I didn't find out how.

(With the comments you just click the comment and there is a delete option.)

And how should I handle it meanwhile? I replaced the content by something like

> (I can't delete this Answer on the mobile App.
>      It was supposed to be a comment)

Anything else I could/should do?

Comment: Oh ok so there is no way so far? (Searching for question already made also doesn't work so well ;) )

Comment: The smartphone apps rely on the Stack API, and the API does not support deletion.

Comment: Just open the post with a browser, then you can do everything.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... good point :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard any idea when these simple things will be implemented on the android/iOS apps as well?

Comment: @NVZ most likely never. It is really not simple, requiring major API changes. Probably weeks worth of development, which is not worth the money spent for not so popular apps.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. But isn't mobile apps the future of internet? I mean most tech companies are now focusing on improving the apps and monetising it. (See: Facebook, Instagram, etc.)

Comment: @NVZ SE is just a small startup company, compared to the internet giants out there. They don't have the resources those giants have, so it's natural to spend those limited resources on the things that bring money. The apps bring 0 income, and as one of the team (Kasra?) said, the amount of downloads is very low compared to what they expected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably a vicious circle. Bad reviews for SE app leads to fewer people using it, fewer users means SE not going to improve the app.

Comment: @NVZ true, but looks like SE thinks the reason is not enough exposure of the app, so they created whole new app from scratch, called "Stack Overflow app" instead, hoping more people will notice it. Well, who knows, they might be right.

Comment: Isn't the community full of programmers with a lot of time to answer problems? ;) Maybe they could work together on those features? ^^